# I have buttons and a textbook in my React App, How do I make the click of the button trigger text input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have buttons that represent the logical operators. For the sake of this example, pretend I have a button that says +
**When I click the + button, I want to see a + inside of the textbox as an input!**

I have provided the code for a button component and the textbox component. In total I have 7 button components.

I realize something has to be onClick (and the code I have there is incorrect, just a placeholder)

button:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

//logic operator buttons
class Logic extends Component {
    state = {};

render() {
return (
  <div
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: "10%",
      top: "20%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }}
  >
    <button
      onClick={this.handleIncrement}
      className={"btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2 p-1"}
    >
      ¬
    </button>
  </div>
);
  }
}

export default Logic;
```

textbox:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Textbox extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
return (
  <div
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: "50%",
      top: "17%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }}
    className="form-group"
  >
    <label for="exampleLogicSymbol">Logic Operator</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      id="exampleInputLogic"
      aria-describedby="logicHelp"
      placeholder="enter formula"
    ></input>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Textbox;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-glitter-y4fwt?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };
  plusOnClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      value: state.value + "+"
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <button onClick={this.plusOnClick}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Essentially you attach an onClick function that updates the input's state value.

Comment: Hello! This worked to an extent, but how would I make the + appear on an existing textbox (another component) rather than making a new textbox? I apologize if this is obvious but I am a beginner!

Comment: that depends on how your component hierarchy is set up

Comment: Gotcha, but would I have to reference the other file textbox.jsx inside of my button.jsx file? Thats what I don't understand!

Comment: is Button a component you're using inside of your Textbox component?

Comment: If so, you would structure Textbox like the above, but pass "plusOnClick" into the Button component as a prop.

Comment: is that how it should be?

Comment: if you can create a codesandbox of your entire app, I can give you a definitive answer

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Logic extends Component {

constructor(){
   this.state={
   value:""
   }

handleIncrement(value)
{
this.setState({
   value:value
             });
}

    render(){
    var Value="¬";
    return(
    <div>
    The value is: {this.state.value}
   
       <button>
        onClick={()=>{this.handleIncrement(Value)}}
        className={"btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2 p-1"}>
        {Value}
       </button>

    </div>);
    }
 }
```